# how to serialize python classes?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a model class defined as;

```
class SiteConfig(object):


    def __init__(self,command,category,frequency,delay):
        self.command=command
        self.category=category
        self.frequency=frequency
        self.delay=delay
```

im calling this model from another class like;

```
    from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
    import httplib
    from models.SiteConfig import *

    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return "Endpoint is not configured", 500


    @app.route('/SitePollingConfiguration',methods=['GET'])
    def SitePollingConfiguration(): 
        response = jsonify(statusCode=httplib.OK, config=BuildSiteConfig())                             
        response.status_code = httplib.OK

        return response

    def BuildSiteConfig():    
        a= SiteConfig('20c','1',60,60)
        print (a)
        return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But im getting **SiteConfig is not JSON serializable** error.

How can i serialize the class object in python?

**EDIT**
i try to use existing flask json encoder;

modified my siteconfig class like;

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

class JsonSerializable(object):
    def toJson(self):
        return JSONEncoder.default(self.__dict__)



class SiteConfig(JsonSerializable):

    def __init__(self,command,category,frequency,delay):
        self.command=command
        self.category=category
        self.frequency=frequency
        self.delay=delay
```

And then calling in my main class like;

```
def ATGSitePollingConfiguration(): 
    response = jsonify(statusCode=httplib.OK, config=BuildATGSiteConfig())                             
    response.status_code = httplib.OK

    return response

def BuildATGSiteConfig():    
    a= SiteConfig('20c','1',60,60)
    print (a)
    return a
```

But still  serializable issue. Sorry im new to python;
can anyone provide simple code sample on how to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html) for class serialisation - alternatively, you need to create a `__repr__` or `__str__` method in the class that provides class serialisation for `json` to consume.

Comment: @match Loading pickled objects can execute arbitrary code, so that's really not something you want to use in a web app.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - in general yes, though if you trust what you're pickling, and you really want to pass the literal serialised class, it might be the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, flask uses `flask.json.JSONEncoder` to encode objects as JSON. In order to `jsonify` your user-defined classes you will need to create a subclass of `JSONEncoder` that implements the serialisation of your class. How you implement the serialisation is up to you, but the easiest method is probably to convert your object into something that `JSONEncoder` already knows about (like a `dict`).

Try adding this code to your app. (You should use the first version of the `SiteConfig` class that you posted, not your modified one).

```
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

# A customized JSON encoder that knows about your SiteConfig class
class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, SiteConfig):
            return obj.__dict__
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

# Tell your flask app to use your customised JSON encoder
app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder
```

With this you should get the response:

```
{
  "config": {
    "category": "1", 
    "command": "20c", 
    "delay": 60, 
    "frequency": 60
  }, 
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

See [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119/) for a similar example.

Comment: I have tried your way. I edited the question with how I try to modify the classes. Could you please tell me the issues there?

Comment: @Ratha my suggestion was to subclass JSONEncoder itself. You should not need to modify your own class. Can you post a complete, runnable example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: My original code sample was how I posted originally in the question. I try to serialise SiteConfig class (which is a model class). But getting json serializable error

Comment: Another solution might be to consider if you need the custom class at all. Could you simply have `BuildATGSiteConfig` return a `dict`? Perhaps it would not work in your case, if so ignore this comment!

Comment: @Ratha the code you posted does not enable me to reproduce the problem or test a solution. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example

Comment: Edited my original question with full class definition

Comment: @Ratha thanks for the edits. I have tested out a solution and updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have posted another question regarding this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738556/how-to-encode-a-list-of-json-objects-in-flask Can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/):

```
import jsonpickle
frozen = jsonpickle.encode(a)
```