# How to encode a list of json objects in flask?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have written my custom jsonencoder as follows;

```
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

from models.AtgSiteToPoll import *


class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, AtgSiteToPoll):
            return obj.__dict__


        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

In my main application I set my encoder as follows; And try to return list of objects from the database. for single object I call encoder as `jsonEncoder.default(a)` But How can I use encoder for list of objects (ie: `formatted_atgsites`)?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import httplib

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder

def BuildATGSite(siteid):
    jsonEncoder = CustomJSONEncoder()
    atgsites=[]
    if siteid is None :
        atgsites = atgsitetopoll.query.all()
    else :
        atgsites = atgsitetopoll.query.filter_by(siteid=siteid).first()

    formatted_atgsites=[]
    a = AtgSiteToPoll()
    if atgsites !=[] :
        for atgs in atgsites:
            formatted_atgsites.append({
                a.SiteId = atgs.siteid
                a.IPAddress = atgs.ipaddress
                a.Port = atgs.port
                a.Category = atgs.category
                a.UserId = atgs.userid
                a.Password = atgs.password
                a.ReceiveTimeoutInMilliSeconds = atgs.receivetimeoutinmilliseconds })
    else:
        a.SiteId = '12345'
        a.IPAddress = '10.10.10.10'
        a.Port = 10001
        a.Category = 1
        a.UserId = 'testuser'
        a.Password = 'testpassword'
        a.ReceiveTimeoutInMilliSeconds = '60'

    return jsonEncoder.default(a)
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated pointer - I've seen you're using that encoder with many classes. You can use `isinstance(something, (SomeClass, AnotherClass, ...))` to make the check easier.

Comment: @viraptor Thank you Ill update it. And answer for my original question?

Answer (score 0):

iirc `CustomJSONEncoder` encodes recusively, however since you're calling `JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)` it's not getting called recursively. Maybe try

```
class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, AtgSiteToPoll):
            return obj.__dict__

        return obj
```

Comment: I did like jsonEncoder.default(formatted_atgsites) but it return null list

Answer (score 0):

Here an example(without Flask).

```
import json

# example of a custom class
class AtgSiteToPoll(object):

    def __init__(self, site_id, ip):
        self.site_id = site_id
        self.ip = ip
        # other properties ...

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'SiteId': self.site_id,
            'IPAddress': self.ip,
            # other properties/structures etc...
        }


class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, AtgSiteToPoll):
            # get our dict
            return obj.to_json()
        # call default encoder(in this case we will process list)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

example_list = [
    AtgSiteToPoll('1', '10.10.10.10'),
    AtgSiteToPoll('2', '10.10.10.11'),
    # other instances...
]

print(json.dumps(example_list, cls=CustomEncoder))
# output:
# [{"IPAddress": "10.10.10.10", "SiteId": "1"}, {"IPAddress": "10.10.10.11", "SiteId": "2"}]
```

Hope this helps. I'm not recommend you to use `obj.__dict__`(will not work in all cases).